# what is the type of URL query parameter in typescript?

Tags: typescript, url, vuejs3, query-string, typescript-eslint

I need to get the election id from the URL in Vue3, to use it as a query parameter in an axios call later in the call. My URL is "http://localhost:8080/#/requestPIN/py6lzerjwjntl4dmr9n77e6x73blk925?electionId=thirdElection"

I am trying to do:

```
get ID(): string | undefined {
return this.$route.query.electionId
```

}

which gives me a typescript error:

```
Type 'LocationQueryValue | LocationQueryValue[]' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
```

what is the right type of the URL query parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assert that the id is a string, then in the return type make sure to say it could potentially return `undefined` still.

```
get ID(): string | undefined {
    return this.$route.query.electionId as string;
}
```

Comment: I am still getting an error with this implementation: Type 'string | LocationQueryValue[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
  Type 'LocationQueryValue[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.Vetur(2322)

Comment: @Blondish Ah right, since it could be an array. What do you want to do when it is an array?

Comment: since its a query param we get from URL, it can only be a string or null or undefined. I just want to get my string and use it haha

Comment: @Blondish Ah alright then, I think a type assertion is better then.

Comment: how do I do a type assertion?

Comment: @Blondish I just edited the answer to show how it would look like.